# How can I set keys for PgUp, PgDn, Home, End, and Delete on linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have Solus installed on a MacBook Air (2008). The keyboard lacks PgUp, PgDn,Home, End, and Delete keys, so I want to assign the commands for those to KbdBrightnessUp, KbdBrightnessDown, alt+KbdBrightnessUp, alt+KbdBrightnessDown, and Eject, respectively.

What are the commands and how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the keycodes that are sent by these keys using `xev` and then remap them using `xmodmap`, like:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode XX = Prior'
xmodmap -e 'keycode YY = Next'
```

where `Prior` and `Next` are what you mean by `PgUp` and `PgDn`.

For reference: [LinuxQuestions.org: Configuring keyboards](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Configuring_keyboards#The_Xmodmap.2FSetxkbmap_Method)

Comment: Thank you! This worked for PgUp, PgDn, and Delete, but I can't seem to get it working for Home and End.

Comment: Note that `Prior` and `Next` do **not** necessarily equate page up and page down, and are actually mean to be more generic. They are just set to the same keycodes in  `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h`. If you truly only want page up and page down, you need to use `Page_Up` and `Page_Down`.